# Java HTTP get request to facebook. Bad request

Tags: facebook-graph-api, jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets, bad-request

I wrote some code to interact with facebook from the client side using a browser control which worked.

I'm trying to run a servlet app for authentication with facebook. The servlet reuses a class I used in the client.

The value of url_conn is: 
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={my-id string}&client_secret={alphanumeric string secret}&fb_exchange_token={Really long alphanumeric string}&grant_type=fb_exchange_token 
. I've removed the actual values where {} are used.

Here's the code. What is wrong? Please provide some guidance. Thanks

```
 try{
        System.out.println("Attempting to open connection");
    conn = (HttpURLConnection) (url_conn.openConnection());
      if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            System.out.println("Throwing IO Exception Successful on " + url_conn.toString());
        throw new IOException(conn.getResponseMessage());
      }
    //  conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset","UTF-8");
      System.out.println("Attempt Successful");

      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(),"UTF-8"));
      String json = reader.readLine();
      JsonReader MyJsonReader = Json.createReader(reader);
      JsonObject jsonObject = MyJsonReader.readObject();

      MyJsonReader.close();
      reader.close();        

      sb = sb.append(jsonObject.toString());    
     }
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("Error From The FileCounter Class " + e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();

}

  conn.disconnect();      
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook can only be accessed over https (the s stands for secure which is basically just http over SSL/TLS). Try using java's HttpsURLConnection class instead of the HttpURLConnection class (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html). For example: `HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();`

Comment: THanks alot man. In addition I had accidentally clipped my key. its now fixed